# How to "not clear" the screen when using dialog?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dialog

`dialog` is a great tool but I can't find a way to use it in a bash script where it would NOT clear the screen beforehand.

I know this is possible if I use `--keep-window` in conjunction with `--and-widget` but in this case I cannot process the user input before displaying the next dialog.

Is it possible to launch a `dialog` command and having it draw its window without clearing the screen ? Is there some trick I'm not aware of ?

**EDIT** (clarification):

Here's a simplified example script of what I'd like to achieve (no, I'm not trying to write a game in bash ;) ): the user input from the first dialog is important to the script and is saved in the variable `selection`

The second dialog should then be displayed in front of the first one. But calling `dialog` automatically clears the screen (and so the first dialog has disappeared)

```
#!/bin/bash

# selection will contain the "tag" of the option selected, either 1, 2 or 3
selection=$(dialog --output-fd 1 --menu "Which cup will you choose ?" 0 0 0 1 "A simple wooden bowl" 2 "A golden jeweled cup" 3 "A plastic goblet")

# and now a second dialog that I'd like to show in front of the first one without clearing the screen

case $selection in
        1)
        dialog --msgbox "You have chosen ... wisely." 0 0
        ;;
        2)
        dialog --msgbox "You chose ... poorly" 0 0
        ;;
        3)
        dialog --msgbox "You must be kidding right ?" 0 0
        ;;
        *)
        dialog --msgbox "You have to choose one !" 0 0
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (`man dialog`) offers the ability to use the secondary screen, restoring the original screen's contents on exit. Is this what you need?

```
dialog --keep-tite --msgbox 'Boo!' 0 0
```

In [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689764/how-to-not-clear-the-screen-when-using-dialog/689794?noredirect=1#comment1304363_689794) you clarify that what you want is a second (and possibly subsequent) box to be overlaid on the first. This is also described in the documentation - with an example. Here's my variation on the theme:

```
dialog --begin 2 2 --msgbox 'Boo!' 0 0 --and-widget --begin 4 4 --msgbox "That's all folks" 0 0
```

Comment: thanks but no, I'd like to call `dialog` once, process the user input, then call `dialog` a second time (with other options) without clearing the screen. For example, dialog #1 would display a menu with n options and dialog #2 would display a messagebox like "you selected option x" without clearing the screen (on top of dialog #1 if you prefer)

Comment: That's what chaining does, just like in the documentation. I've amended the answer for you

Comment: Thanks again, but in this case, I cannot process the user input of the first dialog. Or maybe I'm wrong ? Let's say you want to display a menu with `dialog --menu "select an option" 0 0 0 1 "option 1" 2 "option 2" 3 "option 3"` ... how do you chain that with `--and-widget` so that the second dialog displays a message box with "you selected option x" ?

Comment: I've guessed what you're trying to ask twice now and I'm clearly still not understanding what you want. Please can I suggest you go back to your question and rephrase it to clarify what it is that you want. Feel free to use examples not just showing what you've tried but illustrating what you want. Maybe even counterexamples showing why my suggestions are not what you want. Let's get this cracked...

Comment: ok, I've edited my question ...

Comment: @fvlinden I don't think what you're (now) asking is possible

Comment: @roaimi, yep that was my conclusion too ;)